# Signal Processing Algorithm Psola or Wsola in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I'm trying a long-time to find algorithm PSOLA (Pitch Synchronous Overlap Add) or WSOLA (Waveform Similarity Overlap Add) which are Acoustic or Signal Processing Algorithms.

I found it in c++, but I have no experience in c++ and is difficult to pass it to Pascal. Anyone have this code in Pascal or know where to find it to copy?

Something like this example that is in c++
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mffmtimescale/files/v3%20stable/v3.9/WSOLA.v.3.9.zip/download?use_mirror=ufpr

Comment: Where did you find it in C++ (URL please)? If it is not too complicated, it should be easy to translate it to Delphi.

Comment: Why translate? Why don't you just compile it into a DLL and link from your Delphi app? That way you can avoid risking making errors in your translation.

Comment: In general on StackOverflow, don't assume people know what FLORGBOOGERWAFFLE means.  Spell it out.

Comment: @Warren: I couldn't find FLORGBOOGERWAFFLE (except in your comment), but I could find a few examples of WSOLA. <g>

Comment: @Rudy I think Warren is right, posters shouldn't force us to web search.

Comment: @David: and I agree. I was only kidding.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mffmtimescale/files/v3%20stable/v3.9/WSOLA.v.3.9.zip/download?use_mirror=ufpr

Comment: @Carl: You use that link a lot.  I don't think it means what you think it means (apologies to William Goldman).

Answer (score 3):

Try the [SoundTouch DLL](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/soundtouch-1.6.0.zip), it comes with a Delphi import unit, so you can use the DLL directly. It should not be too hard to compile it. Just download the free VC++ Express from the MS download site and compile it with that or ask someone with VC++ to compile it for you.

FWIW, who knows, with a few modifications, it might also compile with C++Builder.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mffmtimescale/files/v3%20stable/v3.9/WSOLA.v.3.9.zip/download?use_mirror=ufpr

Comment: The problem there is that it is a class, so not so easy to turn into a DLL. You'd have to turn the methods (in the .h file <shudder>) into functions. Not too hard to do, but you should know C++ for that, I guess. Perhaps someone can do that for you? Or use SoundTouch, as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

About one decade ago, I've used [praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) in [FSeqEdit](http://niff.home.xs4all.nl/fs1r/) (Delphi program) to do these type of calculations, but I think the same approach would still work fine today.

I wrote some praat-scripts and execute them via praatcons.exe (console version of praat). You can download the console version from this page:
http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/download_win.html

That works pretty good.

I usually take this approach:
I manually check what type of conversions and calculations need to be done via the GUI version of praat. Once I find what I need, I create a script for it, and run that with the console version.

Praat is very powerful, so if you didn't know about it yet, make sure to check it out.

There's a page that shows how to work with PSOLA resynthesis here:
http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~kyoon/praat-tut/praat-tut2.html

Let me know if you want to see some example code on how to integrate it into your Delphi application (it's pretty straightforward actually).